# Azure Service Duplicate Message Forward

Tags: azure, service, duplicates, queue, bus

I am working in a project which involves Azure Service Bus Queue to place all incoming messages. We used the in-built capability of the Queue for detecting and removing duplicate messages and it works perfect! Now we need to forward the duplicate messages to another queue or some other data store for further analysis instead of dropping/ignoring the duplicate messages and this is what currently the Queue is doing.
So the question is:

1) Is there a simple option to do the same?
2) If not, is there any extension point in which we can inject our custom code to redirect the duplicate message?
3) Any other out of box thought for satisfying this requirement?

Thanks in advance!!!
Happy Thinking :)